# How to use Basic Auth or JWT in Spring Security to create a session for multi tenancy?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, access-token, multi-tenant, spring-session

I am not in the context of login authorization, I validate the request using a basic auth header or JWT token. I have an API that validates the authorization using a token that redirects the requests from somewhere to **Prometheus**. So, I don't want to validate every time a request is made by the same validated source. Only the first one

I want to do **the first login using a token and with that token (validated) create a session using Spring Security with a timeout**.

I thought of using an Interceptor to validate the token and then create a session using `SecurityContextHolder` and `HttpSession`, but I don't know if there is a better way, because I never configured Spring Security before.

Also, I would like to store the session in memory for better performance.

Until now, I just created an Interceptor and validated every request.

Someone can help me?

I didn't do any special configuration of security using **Spring Security**.

The Interceptor that I did:

```
    public class ApiValidationTokenInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public static final String API_CLIENT_KEY_HEADER = "client-key";
    public static final String TENANT_ID = "X-Scope-OrgID";

    @Autowired
    private ApiAuthorizationService apiAuthorizationService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getHeader(TENANT_ID))) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(!validateClientKey(request)) {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.ordinal(), "Invalid domain and client-key token");
            return false;
        }
        response.setHeader(TENANT_ID, "tenant_1");//Hardcoded mas depois mudar para um código hash
        return true;
    }
    
    private boolean validateClientKey(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Validating client-key");
        // checar os valores obtidos pelo token
        String clientKey = request.getHeader(API_CLIENT_KEY_HEADER);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(clientKey)) {
            log.debug("Client key received {}", clientKey);
            if (!apiAuthorizationService.validateClientKey(clientKey)) {
                log.error("Invalid client-key");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            log.error("Client-key not received");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```